# Saving tableview cells

Tags: swift, xcode

i've tried saving the data of my tableview using core data however i haven't been able to get it to work with the way i've setup my code.

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

    cell.taskText.text = tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.taskPriority.image = tasks[indexPath.row].priority

    return cell
```

where tasks is

```
    var tasks = [Task]()
```

and it looks like this

```
class Task {
    var name = ""
    var priority = UIImage()
    var priorityInt = Int()

    convenience init(priority: UIImage, name: String, priorityInt: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.priority = priority
        self.priorityInt = priorityInt
```

PriorityInt is used to change the image which determines the priority of the task.

Comment: where is the problem in your code? I don't see any func which saves data

Comment: show how you are storing the data in tasks

Comment: `Task` must be a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to be able to use It in Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

Leja, "Save data from a table view in the CoreData" doesn't make sense but I will try answering by talking about 2 things.

#### Saving on CoreData

Create your Data Model with your Task model.
Then you will end up having your Task class inheriting from NSManagedObject like this:

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

class TaskMO: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var priority: Int?

}
```

You will use [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) to save your entity with the following code:

```
guard let task = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Task", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as? TaskMO else { return 

do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to save: \(error)")
}
```

#### Show local data on TableView or CollectionView

```
    let managedObjectContext = …
    let tasksFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Task")

    do {
        let fetchedTasks = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(tasksFetch) as! [TaskMO]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch tasks: \(error)")
    }
```

For a huge amount of data, you can even use [NSFetchedResultsController](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-25072)

You can read more about, samples and explanation are well documented. [apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1).